# asp.net sql query help

Tags: asp.net

i have a sql query in asp.net

```
SqlCommand QueidCmd = new SqlCommand("select scope_identity() from table1", conn);
```

i want to take the output and store it in variable
use this variable in another insert query which is just below it...both of these queries are in loop...can this be done??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() from a table; it will do the wrong thing.

Next, the key to the answer to your question is that you can combine multiple commands / queries into a single statement for SqlCommand by separating them with semicolons.  For example:

```
string sql = "DECLARE @scope INT;SET @scope = SCOPE_IDENTITY();UPDATE MyTable SET Val = @scope";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

If you want to introduce variables, you should use a parameterized query, not string concatenation.

You can also use stored procedures -- they're often a cleaner way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in one SQL query:

```
DECLARE @myVariable YOUR_TYPE;
SELECT @myVariable = SCOPE_IDENTITY() FROM table1;
UPDATE table2 SET something = @myVariable;
```

Comment: yes..but this is done in sql server i want it to be done in asp.net

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
object retVal = QueidCmd.ExecuteScalar();
int pk = Convert.ToInt32(retVal); // use this in your next insert
```